# Configure Azure DevOps repository in Databricks through ARM template or Powershell

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-data-factory, azure-databricks

I am looking for a sample ARM template which can setup my Azure DevOps repository into Azure Databricks. This will help me deploy my Master branch directly on ADB workspace.

I tried to do manually on portal and it works, but the repos path for the notebooks shows my email_id, which is not good in Production.

I want to configure through a Powershell OR an ARM template while creating Databricks. The same problem I am facing on Azure dataFactory as well.

Please help me resolve it.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible as of today - there is no API for creating a checkout. It will be possible only when [Databricks Repos](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/repos) will start to provide corresponding API for creating the checkouts of repositories, not only "Update checkout" API that is available right now.

If you're concerned with the checkout created in your own folder, you can just create a Folder inside Repos, call it like "Production", and then do checkout inside that folder (pictures are taken from my [demo of Repos with Azure DevOps](https://github.com/alexott/databricks-nutter-projects-demo)):

[image: create a folder]

[image: checkout the project into folder]

Comment: Thanks, Let me try this

Comment: Is there any restriction on /Repos folder to deploy?  I tried to deploy through Azure Dev ops to /Repos path. I am getting error in logs and its not deploying files... [command]C:\windows\Python\3.7.9\x64\Scripts\databricks.exe workspace import_dir -o --profile AZDO D:\a\r1\a\Notebook-Deploy\DataBricks\Notebooks /Repos/DataBricks/Notebooks {'error_code': 'DIRECTORY_PROTECTED', 'message': 'Top-level folder can only contain repos'}

Comment: Workspace commands doesn't work with Repos - there will be a separate set of APIs for Repos

Comment: Hi @AlexOtt, do you know if these APIs are released? I want to deploy to Repos folder because I like to use the import functionality (over the %run command) for cofigs and utils. So I wonder if we can use Repos API to deploy to higher environments.

Comment: Yes, Repos API (create/update/delete) was released two months ago. Except the API to configure Git token that is coming soon

Answer (score 0):

To deploy Notebooks from your master branch to another workspace, I would recommend to trigger a deployment pipeline from the master branch onto the target databricks worskpace.
That way, no need to setup Repos in the target environment.

1. You use Repos in your development workspace (with your email in path)
2. You commit to the branch you work on and eventually merge / PR to master
3. Once on Master branch, a DevOps pipeline is triggered and deploys the notebook to your target workspace on the path you want

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I shall try this.

Comment: I cant see "Generic Notebook deployment" as a TASK. Is it part of "DevOps for Azure Databricks" ?

Comment: I believe it is a task you have to add from the Marketplace. It was developped by DataThirst.

Comment: Thanks for helping so far. I installed that and now getting error when it tried to deploy.  What does this means? I tried to change path and directories but its not copying any file.      [command]C:\windows\Python\3.7.9\x64\Scripts\databricks.exe workspace import_dir -o --profile AZDO D:\a\r1\a\Notebook-Deploy\DataBricks\Notebooks /Repos/DataBricks/Notebooks
{'error_code': 'DIRECTORY_PROTECTED', 'message': 'Top-level folder can only contain repos'}